# How to use a for loop inside a return in php using functions?

Tags: php, arrays, function, for-loop, echo

i have the following function to populate a birthday selection field

```
function birthday_selector()
{
return '
         <select class="birth_month_select" name="birth_m">
           <option value="">Month</option>
           <option value="01">Jan</option>
           <option value="02">Feb</option>
           <option value="03">Mar</option>
           <option value="04">Apr</option>
           <option value="05">May</option>
           <option value="06">Jun</option>
           <option value="07">Jul</option>
           <option value="08">Aug</option>
           <option value="09">Sep</option>
           <option value="10">Oct</option>
           <option value="11">Nov</option>
           <option value="12">Dec</option>
         </select>
         <!----Select day----->
         <select class="birth_day_select" name="birth_d">
           <option value="">Day</option>

         </select>
         <!----Select Year------>
         <select  class="birth_year_select" name="birth_y">
           <option value="">Year</option>

         </select>';
}
```

now i need to use the following for loop inside this function

THE LOOP

```
             for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
             {
                if($i <=9){ $new_i='0'.$i; }
                else{ $new_i=$i; }

                echo '<option value="'.$new_i.'">'.$new_i.'</option>';
             }
```

How to i use that for loop in  the function **Note:** that im not and expert in arrays so a little help would be appreciated....

**Also Note:** i cant use any echo statements it will screw up my file

Comment: Google for `PHP String concatenation`.

Comment: @Ondkloss i am not so experienced in arrays thats what i meant

Comment: start the string like this: `$str = '';` then concatenate whatever you want to it, then return it like this: `return $str;`

Comment: @Mr.coder Why dont you put a jquery datepicker, something tells me you are misusing php

Comment: Do not use it in a function for return. Just do the total html in that function. Bcz return can only return a string or number vale. not a function. If you want to do make select by php that is possible.

Comment: @meda im not so happy on using plugins i would prefer php

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman the solution seems solid but i still need to use a forloop for the years

Comment: @Mr.coder not every month is 31 days how would you handle that

Comment: "I have a paper shredder that destroys my paper. How do I use the paper against after it's been destroyed?" Simple...don't use the paper shredder until you're done with the paper. If you want to return something more complicated than your fixed string, then DON'T try to build it all as a `return big_ugly_expression`.

Comment: @meda i have a js script which i created for that

Comment: @Mr.coder - don't forget to validate the date on the server, too - people might not have js enables in their browsers.

Comment: @andrewsi i took that into account and did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a string

```
function birthday_selector()
{
            $str =  '<select class="birth_month_select" name="birth_m">';

         for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
         {
            if($i <=9){ $new_i='0'.$i; }
            else{ $new_i=$i; }

            $str .= '<option value="'.$new_i.'">'.$new_i.'</option>';
         }

         $str .= '</select>
            <!----Select day----->
             <select class="birth_day_select" name="birth_d">
               <option value="">Day</option>

             </select>
             <!----Select Year------>
             <select  class="birth_year_select" name="birth_y">
               <option value="">Year</option>

             </select>';
         return $str;
```

}

Comment: will try it and let you know

Comment: Your solution works fine any errors i should i be looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use like in this metod.

```
 <?php
   $str='<select class="birth_month_select" name="birth_m">';
   for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
      {
        if($i <=9){ $new_i='0'.$i; }
        else{ $new_i=$i; }
        $str=$str.'<option value="'.$new_i.'">'.$new_i.'</option>';
      }
      $str=$str."</select>";
      return $str; 
  ?>
```